# Clarification around UIViewController<Delegate> *_variable; declaration in iAdSuite tabbed example (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, iad

From Apples iADSuite tabbed example there is a variable defined with delegate.

```
UIViewController<BannerViewContainer> *_currentController;
```

later it's cast as such

```
_currentController = (UIViewController<BannerViewContainer> *)_tabBarController.selectedViewController;
```

Whats the significance of using "BannerViewContainer" in the declaration, how it relates to the later cast and what's happening under the covers here?

Regards

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to do with delegates here. `BannerViewContainer` is a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1). (You might be confused because delegation is often defined via protocols.)

Declaring a variable or parameter with an angle-bracketed protocol name means that anything assigned to it must be an object which conforms to that protocol: if you try to pass an instance of `UIViewController` or some subclass thereof, you'll get a compiler warning unless that instance is of a `UIViewController` subclass which declares conformance to the `BannerViewContainer` protocol. (That is, you can pass an instance of `FooViewController` if its header file reads `@interface FooViewController : UIViewController <BannerViewContainer>`.)

The cast you see later follows the same pattern as many casts: it's a case where the programmer knows that the object he's assigning meets the requirements for that variable, but the reference he's using doesn't have a matching declaration. That is, the tab bar controller only knows that its selected view controller is a `UIViewController` (or any subclass thereof), but the programmer knows that the views he put into the tab bar are all `UIViewController` subclasses conforming to the `BannerViewContainer` protocol.

Comment: ok, via your redirection, I read link on protocol and for the benefit of future readers see that "Formatter *anObject;" pus this "id <Formatting> anObject;" "can be combined in a single declaration" giving "Formatter <Formatting> *anObject;" Ok lots to digest especially inconspicuous looking lines like "groups all objects...regardless of their positions in the class hierarchy" p.s. I quit doco when I got to section on protocols within protocols..leave that for rainy day :)